# Embeded Vimeo player does not play on Android

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-player

I use this piece of code to load the Vimeo player into a WebView:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String data = "<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/102234762\" width=\"350\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>";
webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

However, when I click the play button, the background becomes gray and the video does not start:
[image]

Any idea guys on what might be wrong and how this could be fixed?
The code is running on a Samsung S4 with Android 4.2.2.

Comment: See :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348